# duplicate items in dropdownlist on an edit page

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, drop-down-menu

I have a page to edit `user profile`.On page load,the data loads on to the page for the given `userid`.The problem is that the dropdownlists have a duplicate item which is selected.as shown below :

[image]

Here is my code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //btnReset.Visible = false;
        BindDisabilityDropDown();
        BindGenderDropDown();
        BindStateDropDown();
        ExtractUserData();
    }
 }
 protected void BindGenderDropDown()
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ss"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblGenders", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        ddlGender.DataSource = ds;
        ddlGender.DataTextField = "GenderName";
        ddlGender.DataValueField = "GenderId";
        ddlGender.DataBind();
    }
    ddlGender.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---", "0"));
    ddlGender.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
 private void ExtractUserData()
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ss"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tblAllUsers where UserId='PL00012'", con);
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            string path = rdr["ProfilePicPath"].ToString();
            hfImagePath.Value = Path.GetFileName(path);
            lblUserId.Text = rdr["UserId"].ToString();
            txtFName.Text = rdr["FirstName"].ToString();
            txtLName.Text = rdr["LastName"].ToString();
            txtEmailAddress.Text = rdr["EmailAdd"].ToString();
            txtContactNumber.Text = rdr["MobileNo"].ToString();
            txtdob.Value = rdr["DOB"].ToString();
            txtStreetAddress.Text = rdr["StreetAddress"].ToString();
            txtZipCode.Text = rdr["ZipCode"].ToString();
            ddlGender.SelectedItem.Text = rdr["Gender"].ToString();
            ddlDisabled.SelectedItem.Text = rdr["Disabled"].ToString();
            ddlState.SelectedItem.Text = rdr["State"].ToString();
            ddlCity.SelectedItem.Text = rdr["City"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

What i am guessing is,the dropdownlist is loaded by `BindGenderDropDown()` and then the `SelectedItem` is added once again by `ExtractData()`.So how can i just avoid the unwanted addition?

Comment: Well,the code is pretty long but this is only thing that has to do with the initial loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following while selecting `DropdownList` `SelectedItem` in `ExtractUserData()` method:

```
ddlGender.SelectedIndex = ddlGender.Items.IndexOf(ddlGender.Items.FindByText(rdr["Gender"].ToString()));
```

Your code `ddlGender.SelectedItem.Text = rdr["Gender"].ToString();` is displaying `---Select---` with `rdr["Gender"].ToString()`. This code doesn't change the Items but only chooses the item.

Comment: That worked.However,it is not working for my City which comes from ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged. Why?

Comment: you have to bind ddlCity after ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged, then only you can assign the selected value.

Comment: ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged() itself binds ddlCity.

Comment: If ddlCity is bound to its data after ddlState_selectedIndexChanged, then you shouldn't have any problems at all. Be sure that assigning ddlState value from code behind doesn't itself fire ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged.

Comment: Yeah,i did that and its not binding anything in ddlCity.I guess i should be asking this in a new thread.Thank you for the help bro

Comment: Read the earlier comment.

Comment: I guess thats what selectedIndexChanged are for.When i select a state,it triggers ddlcity to populate with cities in selected state...and then it should be selecting a city by ExtractUserData()

Comment: Yes selectedIndex function is that... but note that selectedIndex only fires when user selects any Item in dropdownlist, but not when you are assigning value from program (code behind) itself. So you must bind ddlCity again by sending ddlState value just like what you did in ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged.

Answer (score 1):

it may help you.

```
if (ddlGender.Items.Contains(ddlGender.Items.FindByText(rdr["Gender"].ToString())))
            {
                ddlGender.Items.FindByText(rdr["Gender"].ToString()).Selected = true;
            }
```

In your case, `ddlGender.SelectedItem.Text = rdr["Gender"].ToString();` is changing text of selected index and so it is changing `--Select--` to `Your Selected Value`.

and for selection of Item in Dropdown, I'd suggest to use below code.

```
ddlGender.SelectedValue = rdr["GenderId"].ToString();
```

Comment: Even, in all `dropdown` selection needs to be updated

Comment: Unfortunately,it doesnt make a selection.Comes up as -----Select----